# Left Join Count

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Ok i think i am going about this the wrong way possibly, but i have tried so many different ideas and cannot seem to find the right way to do this, so hoped somebody might be able to nudge me in the right direction.

Basically i record the ip address of visitors as they visit my website, and then identify which of the ip addresses belong to businesses.

So table one has a long list of ip addresses of people who have visited my website and table two has a list of ip addresses i have identified.

Now what i am trying to do is find out how many of the IP addresses in Table 1 have been identified.

The code i have below matches and groups the ip addresses and shows me how many times the ip address in table 2 appears in table one.

However what i am trying to get is just one number and not a group of numbers, i have tried writing the query several ways but can only get it to work with a group

```
SELECT ip_stats.ip, COUNT(ip_stats.ip) 
FROM ip_stats 
LEFT JOIN main USING (ip)
GROUP BY ip_stats.ip
```

ip_stats is table one and has the long list of people visiting my website.
main is table two and contains the details of the IP addresses which have been identified.

both tables have their own primary key both are which are id.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information about your tables, such as their schema. (whhich one is `main` and which is `ip_stats`? Is `ip_stats.ip` a unique primary key? etc)

Comment: thanks i have just updated the table details a little more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` the `ip` on `main` table

```
SELECT ip_stats.ip, COUNT(`main`.ip)
FROM ip_stats 
LEFT JOIN main USING (ip)
GROUP BY ip_stats.ip
```

**UPDATE 1**

ah ok, so you only want one value for all `ip` that are present on main table right? then you don't need to use `LEFT JOIN` for this, instead use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip_stats.ip)
FROM ip_stats 
     INNER JOIN main USING (ip)
```

`DISTINCT` was added so only unique values are being counted.

Comment: Thanks but this just groups the results still what i am trying to find out is how to get just one number and not a group of results, i know i have group but it's the only way i can get it to work and i would like to identify another way which would give me just one number.

Comment: @StanWilliams try my updated answer above. use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: Cool, thanks, ok what i want to do is take the ip from main and match them against the ip_stats table, but i want to identify every record in ip_stats even if it is repeated, and i think your code just identified it once, am i correct?

Comment: @StanWilliams yes, you can get rid of the `DISTINCT` if you want to.

Comment: thanks, i am getting a number but it seems to low as it says 214 my Ip_stats table has 4, 224 records in it and i have already identified 1,124 and so i'm not sure if i am doing something wrong?

Comment: @StanWilliams weired. can you atleast printscreen the records. I just want to see that. maybe you are doing something not right. (*or maybe also I am*)

Comment: OK, I think its me i think that number is correct  and that at some point  i cleared the database and started again, so it works.  again sorry for the confusion and thanks for you help.